# SOAP requests run in SOAP UI but not in WSO2ESB "Try this service" page, so the related scheduled task doesn't work

Tags: web-services, wso2, scheduled-tasks, soapui, wso2-esb

I have deployed a custom Proxy Service in WSO2 ESB and I can't obtain any response from the web service i call with it in "Try this service" page. I've tried to send the request with SOAP UI passing through the Proxy Service of WSO2ESB (I put the endpoint of the Proxy Service, and NOT of the WS, in SOAP UI) and it works correctly. The same SOAP request doesn't work in the WSO2ESB page unreasonably.

So, when i create a scheduled task with the selected proxy service it returns me an error. I don't know how to change the content of the SOAP message in order to make it correct for ESB.

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/sri/service/2.0">
  <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
   <ns:QueryStructure>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ns:Query>
    <RegistryInterface xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd" xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common" xmlns:compact="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/compact" xmlns:cross="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/cross" xmlns:generic="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:query="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/query" xmlns:structure="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/structure" xmlns:registry="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/registry" xmlns:utility="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/utility" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <ID>JD014</ID>
        <Test>true</Test>
        <Truncated>false</Truncated>
        <Name xml:lang="en">Trans46302</Name>
        <Prepared>2001-03-11T09:30:47-05:00</Prepared>
        <Sender id="BIS"/>
    </Header>
    <QueryStructureRequest resolveReferences="false">
   <registry:DataflowRef/>
</QueryStructureRequest>
</RegistryInterface>
     </ns:Query>
  </ns:QueryStructure>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This runs on SOAP UI (through ESB) and not on the same ESB.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the content of a message you can use [Payload Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/PayloadFactory+Mediator).

There's also an [example](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14287837) on how to do this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is not to change the payload, but to understand why this SOAP message is not correct for ESB and correct for SOAP UI. I must insert this message into a task scheduled on the ESB, but i don't know how to write some functioning code different from this, 'cos this is however correct.

Comment: I solved it changing the message in this way: '<body> 
    <ns:QueryStructure xmlns="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/sri/service/2.0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/sri/service/2.0">' at the beginning of the query replacing everithing before "optional" line (and changing related tags in the end of message.